# Tomcat 8 not launching from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

*installed tomcat and the service is running, after stopping tomcat when trying to launch the same from eclipse getting following error*

installed tomcat using [digital ocean link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**VM arguments** : **Dcatalina.home="/opt/tomcat"**

```
2016-09-29 20:25:59.624 ERROR 10068 --- :Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.mmt.application.PwaApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'catalina.home' in string value "file:${catalina.home}/conf/pwaHLP.properties"
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at com.mmt.application.PwaApplication.main(PwaApplication.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'catalina.home' in string value "file:${catalina.home}/conf/pwaHLP.properties"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:571)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:359)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:255)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168)
... 18 more

2016-09-29 20:25:59.628  INFO 10068 --- :Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/devang/repo/PWA-HLP/target/classes/]
```

Comment: looks like you might be missing a `-` in front of `Dcatalina.home="/opt/tomcat"`

Comment: - is there in the launch configuration, under VM arguments category